# FloatingActionButton появляется на следующем фрагменте

Tags: java, android

Есть фрагмент с `RecyclerView` и `FloatingActionButton`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStartHelpMessageExcavation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/tvStartHelpMessageExc"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nsv"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

При нажатии на элемент `RecyclerView` (`CardView`) открывается новый фрагмент

```
FragmentTransaction fTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        LayerProbeFrag fragment = new LayerProbeFrag();
                        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        fTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                        fTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        fTransaction.commit();
```

и в нем показывается `FloatingActionButton` с предыдущего фрагмента, хотя в нем нигде не прописан `FloatingActionButton`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Как сделать,чтобы `FloatingActionButton`  не появлялась в новом фрагменте?

Comment: `ViewPager` заполняете какими фрагментами?

Comment: Два фрагмента там с RecyclerView. Floats там тоже нигде нет.

Comment: Используете суперкласс для создания фрагментов с `RecyclerView`?Или может случайно указали не тот файл с разметкой

Comment: @ujinUkr таки не доглядел, в новых фрагментах старые xml стояли. Спасибо за наводку!